# Clustering a noisy data or with outliers

Tags: r, machine-learning, clustering

I have a noisy data of two variables like this.

```
x1 <- rep(seq(0,1, 0.1), each = 3000)
set.seed(123)
y1 <- rep (c(0.2, 0.8, 0.3, 0.9, 0.65, 0.35,0.7,0.1,0.25, 0.3, 0.95), each = 3000)
set.seed(1234)
e1 = rnorm(length(x1), 0.07,0.07)
set.seed(1223)
e2 = rnorm(length(x1), 0.07,0.07)
set.seed(1334)
yn <- rnorm(20000, 0.5,0.9)
set.seed(2344)
xn <- rnorm(20000, 0.5,0.9)
y <- c(y1 + e1,yn) 
x <- c(x1 + e2, xn) 
plot(x,y,  xlim=c(0,1.2), ylim = c(0,1.2), pch = ".", col = "gray40")
```

I can visually see there are potential 10 clusters in closer look.

[image]

However the whole data has much points spread:

```
plot(x,y,   pch = ".", col = "gray40")
```

[image]

I would like to make 10 clusters. I tried K-means cluster analysis.

```
xm1 <- cbind(x,y)
cl1 <- kmeans(xm1, 10)
colrs <- c("red", "green", "blue1", "pink", "green4","tan", 
 "gray40", "yellow", "black", "purple") 
plot(xm1, col = colrs[cl1$cluster], pch = ".", xlim=c(0,1.2), ylim = c(0,1.2))
```

[image]

```
plot(xm1, col = colrs[cl1$cluster], pch = ".")
```

[image]

Is there anyway (may be kernel k-means, nearest neighbors) that can do more justice to this type of data. If so how can I do this ?

Comment: What's wrong with what you have so far? Why is what you have (the **k-means cluster analysis**) unacceptable?

Comment: Have a look to dbscan or optics algorithms (see http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Data_Mining_Algorithms_In_R/Clustering/Density-Based_Clustering#Important_Concepts)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As your data seems to be composed of Gaussian Mixtures, try **Gaussian Mixture Modeling** (aka: EM clustering). This should yield results far superior to k-means on this type of data.

If your "noise" is uniform distributed, you can also add a uniform distribution to your mixture model.

If your data is much less clean, consider using DBSCAN, MeanShift, OPTICS, HDBSCAN*, ... - **density based clusterig** seems to be appropriate for this data. DBSCAN is also very tolerant to noise (the "N" is for noise).

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you to look at [this](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0806.2976.pdf) article. The authors propose robust method where the outliers are removed and the rest of data is clustered. That is why they called the method "trimming". There was also an R package **tclust** but according to [this](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tclust/index.html), it was removed from CRAN. Anyway, the article is worth reading.