# Locality Preserving Projection (LPP) VS Principal Component Analysis (PCA)

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction

What's the difference between Locality Preserving Projection (LPP) and Principal Component Analysis (PCA)?

This is our data. It's a 3D plot. Here I use LPP and PCA to reduce the 3D data to 2D data. It gives different results. I know that PCA reduces the dimension on maximum variance, but what about LPP?

[image]

**Locality Preserving Projection (LPP)**

[image]

**Principal Component Analysis (PCA)**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you note in your question, PCA attempts to reduce dimensionality while maximizing variance accounted for.  LPP on the other hand attempts to reduce the number of dimensions while maximizing a sense of nearness to one's neighbors.

I located the following website (https://notebook.community/jakevdp/lpproj/Example) which appears to give a nice explanation with some sample code in Python.

Comment: So LPP and PCA are almost the same, but LPP is slightly better than PCA because LPP remove outlisers?

Comment: They are accomplishing similar goals:  dimension reduction.  And though I'd rather someone with more expertise with LPP speak to that specifically, I can confirm that PCA can be very strongly influenced by outliers in the data.

Comment: I'm looking for a better method to reduce the dimensions. I have been looking at UMAP, but UMAP does not give back a projection matrix like LDA, PCA, LPP does. Do you have any suggestions for a good dimension reduction method?

Comment: To be able to help more with that, I'd need to know what the goal of the dimension reduction process is...this will often guide you toward one option over another.

Comment: My goal is to remove outliers and separate the classes from each other as much as possible. I know there exist LDA. I'm using it, it's very good. But I need something better.

Comment: I want to reduce multidimensions to 2D. And hopefully, the data would be like round little balls on the screen.

Comment: If you know you definitely have outliers (univariate or multivariate), then a robust approach like LPP is probably your better option.  You can also consider non-dimensional approaches like nearest neighbor algorithms if you are really just looking for groupings.

Comment: Like as K-means clustering?

Comment: That is one possible clustering option, and depending on the options you choose, you might be able to avoid issues with outliers.

Comment: What do you recommend if you got issues with outliers?

Comment: Try this post:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/110428/clustering-a-noisy-data-or-with-outliers

Comment: Gregg, I think I found what I'm looking for - Independent Component Analysis.